# Using CASE with DATE Type in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, case

I want to use `CASE` with DATE Type in `WHERE` clause, so when `@birthFrom` or `@birthTo` is `NULL` return all record.

```
DECLARE @birthFrom DATE= NULL --'19941012'
DECLARE @birthTo DATE= NULL --'20101012'

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.bbmf
WHERE   birth BETWEEN ( CASE @birthFrom
                      WHEN NULL THEN birth
                      ELSE @birthFrom
                    END )
          AND     ( CASE @birthTo
                      WHEN NULL THEN birth
                      ELSE @birthTo
                    END )
```

**My problem is:** when I execute the above code there is no record selected

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your `case` doesn't work is that `null` is not equal to `null`.  The expression `null = null` evaluates to `unknown`.  For example:

```
select case null when null then 1 else 2 end
-->
2
```

You could make it work like `case when x is null`.  Note the use of `is` as opposed to `=`:

```
declare @x int = null
select case when @x is null then 1 else 2 end
-->
1
```

For more details, see the [Wikipedia article on three valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic).

A simpler way is to omit the case altogether:

```
where   (@birthFrom is null or @birthFrom <= birth)
        and (@birthTo is null or birth <= @birthTo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one mistake in `CASE` statement, you have added `@birthFrom` instead of `@birthTo`

```
WHERE   birth BETWEEN ( CASE @birthFrom
                      WHEN NULL THEN birth
                      ELSE @birthFrom
                    END )
          AND     ( CASE @birthFrom <----it should be @birthTo
-------------------------^^^^^^^^^^
                      WHEN NULL THEN birth
                      ELSE @birthTo
                    END )
```